# How to translate position absolute div on top of another regardless of scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a picture, and some text. When user hovers on text, I want picture to show some other picture. I have other pictures and when user hovers on text I want the changed picture to be the currently visible picture on the viewport.

I have a div on the page, and I want another div to hover on top of the first. I got it working, but it breaks on scroll. I want the `position: absolute` style to stay and want to transform using `translate`. The reason I need to compute the bounds and translate, is the `.onpage` div changes so where I have to show it changes.

```js
let $onpage = document.getElementById('onpage');
let $onhover = document.getElementById('onhover');

let $triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

function fTranslate(pos) {
  return el => {
    el.style.transform = `translate(${pos[0]}px,${pos[1]}px)`;
  };
}

function show() {
  let bounds = $onpage.getBoundingClientRect();
  let pos = [bounds.left, bounds.top];

  fTranslate(pos)($onhover);
}

$triggers.forEach(_ => {
  _.addEventListener('mouseover', _ => {
    show();  
  });
});
```

```css
.on-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.on-page {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background: red;
}

.on-hover {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  height: 10000px;
}

#trigger1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#trigger2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div id='onpage' class="on-page"></div>

<span id="trigger1" class="trigger">Hover 1</span>
<p>Some content
<span id="trigger2" class="trigger">Hover 2</span>
</p>

<div id='onhover' class="on-hover"></div>

<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the element to stay there, then don't translate it away? It's kind of unclear what the end result should be as your wish contradicts what you're trying to do.

Comment: I actually calculate the position and show the element on scroll.

Comment: Rephrase your question so that it makes sense, please.

Comment: Could you instead explain why are you doing what you're doing? Why would you want a DIV to overlay a DIV on scroll? Are you trying to prevent user click on that lower DIV? What are you trying **actually** to achieve? Seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go you just had to calculate the scroll offset of the window

```js
let $onpage = document.getElementById('onpage');
let $onhover = document.getElementById('onhover');

function fTranslate(pos) {
  return el => {
    el.style.transform = `translate(${pos[0]}px,${pos[1]}px)`;
  };
}

let bounds = $onpage.getBoundingClientRect();
let pos = [bounds.left, bounds.top];

fTranslate(pos)($onhover);

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let bounds = $onpage.getBoundingClientRect();

    const scrollLeft =
      window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 const offsetLeft = bounds.left + scrollLeft;
    const offsetTop = bounds.top + scrollTop;
  let pos = [offsetLeft, offsetTop];

  fTranslate(pos)($onhover);
});
```

```css
.on-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.on-page {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background: red;
}

.on-hover {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div id='onpage' class="on-page"></div>

<div id='onhover' class="on-hover"></div>

<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if I misunderstood. If you are looking to get the grey square to remain fixed, you can change the values in your translate to be negative to give you a positive offset.

```js
let $onpage = document.getElementById('onpage');
let $onhover = document.getElementById('onhover');

function fTranslate(pos) {
  return el => {
    el.style.transform = `translate(${-pos[0]}px,${-pos[1]}px)`;
  };
}

let bounds = $onpage.getBoundingClientRect();
let pos = [bounds.left, bounds.top];

fTranslate(pos)($onhover);

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let bounds = $onpage.getBoundingClientRect();
  let pos = [bounds.left, bounds.top];

  fTranslate(pos)($onhover);
});
```

```css
.on-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.on-page {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background: red;
}

.on-hover {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div id='onpage' class="on-page"></div>

<div id='onhover' class="on-hover"></div>

<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your gray div flickers from time to time